# How can I get bixby to prompt for optional inputs?

Tags: bixby

At a high level, I would like to set up an action that has some required inputs and some optional ones. After the user begins, he/she will be prompted for any required inputs that are missing. If/when the required inputs are collected, i would like to ask if the user wants to specify more optional inputs.

The specific use case is a voice-based real estate search. I have some required inputs set up like zip code, price, and number of bedrooms. Then I would like bixby to ask "would you like to refine your search even further?" and if the user says yes, we can ask about number of bathrooms, parking arrangements, and other more niche parameters. I do not want to make all of these required and have to prompt everyone if they want to filter by "pools" or some parameter not widely used. And being voice-based, I do not want to just have it as a checkbox on the screen because someone on the speaker won't be able to use that parameter then.

I have thought of 2 potential solutions but I do not know if they will work (at least without relying on the controls on screen for a voice-based capsule):

1) Make the search into a transaction and then instead of a normal confirmation, try to shoe-horn the confirmation to ask if the user wants to add more refinements. Maybe something like the bank transfer one but a negative confirmation would cause bixby to ask for information that she didnt ask for before: https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/sample-capsules/walkthroughs/simple-transactional#sample-capsule-walkthrough

2) Make 2 more required inputs, one boolean called "WantsOptionalParameters" and the other called "OptionalParameters" that will be a structure containing all of the optional parameters. Then it would prompt for WantsOptionalParameters like a normal required input, and if that is "True", I can have a sub-action that will ask for each one of the parameters to construct an OptionalParameters object. then we could feed that output into the search. And alternatively, if WantsOptionalParameters is false, we can automatically construct OptionalParameters with all negative responses and feed that into the original action.

Both of these solutions will take a bunch more research and testing and i don't even know if they will work, so i was hoping to call on the wisdom of you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my take on it for what its worth. Every domain has key inputs that are typically used to start the conversation and optional inputs that can refine the conversation.

Some general ways to start conversation for the real estate example (totally driven by my own experience, perhaps there are more)

- Hows the real estate market in 90210?
- Show me homes under $250K in Los Angeles?
- Show me homes with 4 bedrooms (near me?)

You can club such inputs into an `input-group` called **RequiredInputs** that requires [`OneOrMoreOf`](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/action.collect.input-group.requires) these parameters to get the capsule started.

You can also collect the optional/niche inputs in another `input-group` called **OptionalInputs** that requires [`ZeroOrMoreOf`](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/action.collect.input-group.requires) and feed them into your capsule logic

Its also possible that all inputs are equally important and are all Optional! It is totally dependent on the domain and how the capsule developer might handle such inputs.

But in a general sense, once the set of inputs is in and the initial results are shown to the user, the capsule developer then has a great amount of control to

- Shape the future conversation AND
- Highlight capsule capabilities.

So, rather than presenting the user with a set of options, you can control the conversation and offer options that provide most value to the user (and to the capsule developer!)

e.g your capsule is capable of deep analyzing and refining results in a way that no other capsule on the market can do. So, you want to highlight this capability as the first choice via [`followup`](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/result-view.followup)

Or You may have a conversation path based on prior experiences and your knowledge of the domain. So, you could say, I can refine the results further by X, Y, Z options.

This scenario is more likely to be useful and less likely to overwhelm (with options) the end user.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Cool, I really appreciate the insight. These are some options that I was not aware of so i will research and play around with these and ask any follow up questions if needed. I think i will try to have the absolute basic inputs as required and then maybe ask for optional ones in follow up to narrow down results. Thanks so much!